# undefined method `paginate' for #<Artist:0xd7a8db8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, friendly-id

im using rails 4 and will_paginate and friendly_id

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.6'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'sorcery'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7' 
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
```

in the artist controller

```
  def show
    @artist = Artist.friendly.find(params[:id]).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

and the view artists.show.html.erb

```
<div class="text-center">
<%= will_paginate %>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
  <% @artist.songs.each do |song| %>
      <%= link_to song.title, artist_song_path(@artist, song), class: 'list-group-item' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and it throw me this error

```
NoMethodError in ArtistsController#show
undefined method `paginate' for #<Artist:0xd7a8db8>
Extracted source (around line #3):

class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @artist = Artist.friendly.find(params[:id]).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

help please !

update ;

i fix it

in artist controller

```
  def show
    @artist = Artist.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @songs = @artist.songs.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

thanks @Ben Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paginate` method will only work on a collection of records, not a single one.  When you use `find`, a single record is returned.  If you wanted to be able to paginate, using `where` instead of `find` would be necessary, though only in an index route where multiple artists are potentially going to be returned.